# Mono & DeflateStream

Tags: mono, deflatestream

I have a simple code

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abracadabra");
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
DeflateStream ds = new DeflateStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, false);
ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

DeflateStream ds2 = new DeflateStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress, false);
byte[]  buffer2 = new byte[ms.Length];
ds2.Read(buffer2, 0, (int)ms.Length);
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer2));
```

And when reading from ds2, i have the following:

> Stacktrace:
>
> at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.ReadZStream
>   (intptr,intptr,int) <0x00004>
>
> at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.ReadZStream
>   (intptr,intptr,int) <0x00004>
>
> at
>   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.ReadInternal
>   (byte[],int,int) [0x00031] in
>   C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.3\mcs\class\System\System.IO.Compression\DeflateStream.cs:192
>
> at
>   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read
>   (byte[],int,int) [0x00086] in
>   C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.3\mcs\class\System\System.IO.Compression\DeflateStream.cs:214
>
> at testtesttest.MainClass.Main
>   (string[]) [0x00041] in
>   C:\Users\ilukyanov\Desktop\Cassini\GZipDemo\Main.cs:27
>
> at (wrapper runtime-invoke)
>   .runtime_invoke_void_object
>   (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
>
> This application has requested the
>   Runtime to terminate it in an unusual
>   way. Please contact the application's
>   support team for more information.

This problem appears in Mono 2.6.1 & 2.6.3...

Is there any known way to successfully read from DeflateStream in Mono? Or maybe there are some third-party open-source assemblies with the same functionality?

Comment: Important remark: my platform is Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call zlib natively using Interop with DllImport.
Only trick is to use the right size in the structures and to include the shared library in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, if you are on a Unix platform.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my platform is windows =(

Answer (score 0):

Please file a bug against Mono. If you do so, it might get fixed in time for 2.6.4.

Comment: It's already there with low priority =( Btw Novell's implementation og GZipStream is hillarious... It's simply decorates DeflateStream and adds nothing to it's functionality...